# spicy-client assertion failure after computer crash

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, fedora, qemu

I usually use spice-client to connect to remote VMs without any problem.
Today during usual work my pc freezed (I am strong confident that this is not due to spice) and forced me to brute shutdown.

Now I'm trying to reopen the connection to the remote VM, but I think that spice can't open a display handler. All I get is an assertion failure:

```
GSpice-Message: main channel: opened

(spicy:2066): GSpice-CRITICAL **: display_handle_monitors_config: assertion 'config->count > 0' failed
```

with the process hanging.

How can I resolve this?